# Magento Table rate with Shopping Cart Price Rules not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am try to create shipping rules for my magento site.

My requirement is like this.

**1) Some product has free shipping in USA and rest of all product are have shipping charges.
2) When user select Alaska than all product are having shipping rate.**

So i have use **Table rate with Price Vs.Destination** and my table rate is as per bellow

```
Country | Region/State | Zip/Postal Code | Order Subtotal (and above) | Shipping Price

USA     |   *          |     *           |       100                  |   10
USA     |   *          |     *           |       200                  |   20
USA     |   *          |     *           |       300                  |   30
USA     |   *          |     *           |       400                  |   40
USA     |   *          |     *           |       500                  |   45
USA     |   *          |     *           |       600                  |   55
USA     |   *          |     *           |       700                  |   60
```

And i have created one shopping cart promotion rules for product has **sku prod-333** and **Shipping State/Province  is not  Alaska** than shipping is **free**.

Bellow is my condition

[image: Condition]

And Action for that condition is

[image]

it works fine when i added product which has a sku: prod-333. If i select USA and NEW YORK than its shipping rate is free and Table rate is display properly in Estimated shipping block of magento.

[image]

But When i added another product in cart at that time than its not showing table rate shipping method. I needed to calculate shipping rate for rest of the product i added in the cart excluding sku-333.

[image]

So please help me out from this issue. Please suggest me solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it may be conflict with the condition you have put for sku prod-333. Because similar issue i have faced. and there is a confliction so i simply remove that condition and it is working fine now.